# @Inject annotation in EJB doesn't work with Logger

Tags: java, logging, dependency-injection, jboss

I use **@Inject Logger** to inject the logger using the following snippet:

```
public class Resources {

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

}
```

The above works for the war module, but it return a *NullPointerException* on ejb module.

My container is JBoss 6.4 EAP.

What's the issue with this ?

Comment: do you have beans.xml placed in your ejb's META-INF directory?

Comment: Where are you getting this NPE?

Comment: Thank you @mendieta, beans.xml was missing !!

Comment: You are very welcome! I also posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have beans.xml in your ejb's META-INF directory (as specified here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html)